# Calling a method in activity class from my Async Thread

Tags: java, android

```
public class AycanClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> implements IAppointments {

    Activity activity;

    public AycanClass(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           super.onPostExecute(result); 
           activity.setFilters(value);      
    }     
}
```

Now in my MainActivity class i have method like this.

```
public void setFilters(String result){

}
```

I am not able to call this method.

```
The method setFilters(result) is undefined for the type Activity
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: make your activity implement an interface that will contain that method.

```
public interface FilterableActivity {
 public void setFilters(String result);
}
```

And the activity should look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements FilterableActivity {

 ...
 public void setFilters(String result){

 }
}
```

And just pass a FilterableActivity as a parameter to the Asynctask.

```
public AycanClass(FilterableActivity activity){
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

Comment: Not sure that it's the best way to go for scalability. You should use an interface.

Comment: OK, you just copy/paste my answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

You should use an interface with a single method : here "setFilters"
Your activity should implements this interface and your asynctask constructor will ask for an instance of your interface.

```
public interface ISetFiltersInterface{
public void setFilters(List<Filter>);
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements ISetFiltersInterface{
...
    public void setFilters(List<Filter>){
        //TODO
}
}

public class AycanClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> implements IAppointments {

ISetFiltersInterface delegate;

public AycanClass(ISetFiltersInterface delegate){
    this.delegate = delegate;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       super.onPostExecute(result); 
       delegate.setFilters(value);      
}     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the Activity interface doesn't have a setFilter function defined.

You should define this in a Interface and let your Activity implements this one.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class AycanClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> implements IAppointments {

    Activity activity;
    MainActivity mainactivityobjectname;

    public AycanClass(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           super.onPostExecute(result); 
           mainactivityobjectname.setFilters(value);      
    }     
}
```

Comment: Useless info without explaining why it doesn't work. Also mainactivityobjectname is never set.

Comment: I shall rephrase: the Question Asker (and other reading this question) always want to know: why the problem occurs and how to fix it. It doesn't benefit anyone if you just post some code without any explanation and is incomplete.

Comment: @PoweRoy I am sorry yesterday I was in trouble here . . .

Comment: @PoweRoy  Sorry  for my inconvinent I am having worst situations here hence i need to act like I m Sorry My Friend

Comment: Could you undo all the downvotes I received yesterday. Are they from you? If not nvm